# How do i fix this compile error in my ms access code?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this line:

```
Me.Combo103 = "SELECT profile from table where profile < '" & CAST(me.width AS DOUBLE) & "'"
```

It gives me an error: compile error: expected: list separator or )

Do you know what might cause the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For MS access use `cdbl(me.width) ` instead of `CAST(me.width AS DOUBLE)` try this `Me.Combo103 = "SELECT profile from table where profile < " & cdbl(me.width) `

Comment: `CAST` doesn't exist in Access VBA. You may be looking for `CDbl()`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to achieve, there are several problems:

1. You are trying to assign a query to the value of a ComboBox. Use the RowSource property.
2. "CAST(me.width AS DOUBLE)" can't be evaluated, use "CDbl(Me.Width)" instead.
3. You use a "double" number as a string in the query…

Try something like this:

```
Me.Combo103.RowSource = "SELECT profile from table where " & BuildCriteria("profile", dbDouble, "<" & CStr(Me.Width))
```